# LibTIFF reading and writing RGBA image in c++

Tags: c++, libtiff

I am new to C++ and I am using LibTIFF for reading and writing RGBA image. However, the written image is not the same as image read.
Could anybody please let me know where am I making mistake and correct my code
? My code is given bellow: I have follow many tutorials but couldn't figure out the problem.

```
TIFF *target = TIFFOpen("im16temp.tif", "r");

uint32 width;
uint32 height;
uint32 *rasterTarget;
uint32 BPP;


TIFFGetField(target, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &width);       // uint32 width;
TIFFGetField(target, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &height);    // uint32 height;
TIFFGetField(target, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, &BPP);
uint32 npixels = width * height;

int  sampleperpixel = 4;

rasterTarget = (uint32 *) _TIFFmalloc(npixels * sizeof(uint32) * 2);

TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented(target, width, height, rasterTarget,
ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT, 0);

TIFF *outnew= TIFFOpen("new.tif", "w");




TIFFSetField (outnew, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width);  // set the width of the image

TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height);    // set the height of the image
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, sampleperpixel);   // set number of channels per pixel
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 16);    // set the size of the channels
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATION_TOPLEFT);    // set the origin of the image.
//   Some other essential fields to set that you do not have to understand for now.
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG);
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_RGB);
tsize_t linebytes = sampleperpixel * width * 2 ;     // length in memory of one row of pixel in the image.

cout<< "Lien of linebytes : "<<linebytes<<endl;



unsigned char *buf = NULL;        // buffer used to store the row of pixel information for writing to file
//    Allocating memory to store the pixels of current row
if (TIFFScanlineSize(outnew)!=linebytes)
    buf =(unsigned char *)_TIFFmalloc(linebytes);
else
    buf = (unsigned char *)_TIFFmalloc(TIFFScanlineSize(outnew));

// We set the strip size of the file to be size of one row of pixels
TIFFSetField(outnew, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, TIFFDefaultStripSize(outnew, linebytes));



//Now writing image to the file one strip at a time
for (uint32 row = 0; row <  height; row++)
{

    //memcpy(buf, &rasterTargetinput[( height1-row-1)*linebytes], linebytes);    // check the index here, and figure out why not using h*linebytes
    memcpy(buf, &rasterTarget[row*linebytes], linebytes);    // check the index here, and figure out why not using h*linebytes
    //memcpy(buf, &rasterTarget[(height-row-1)*linebytes], linebytes);
    if (TIFFWriteScanline(outnew, buf, row, 0) < 0)
    break;
}
```

Here is the output of the tiffdump for input and output image.

Output image:

```
Magic: 0x4d4d <big-endian> Version: 0x2a <ClassicTIFF>
Directory 0: offset 392 (0x188) next 0 (0)
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<8>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<8>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 3<16 16 16>
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Photometric (262) SHORT (3) 1<2>
StripOffsets (273) LONG (4) 1<8>
Orientation (274) SHORT (3) 1<1>
SamplesPerPixel (277) SHORT (3) 1<3>
RowsPerStrip (278) SHORT (3) 1<48>
StripByteCounts (279) LONG (4) 1<384>
PlanarConfig (284) SHORT (3) 1<1>
SampleFormat (339) SHORT (3) 3<1 1 1>
```

input image:

```
Magic: 0x4d4d <big-endian> Version: 0x2a <ClassicTIFF>
Directory 0: offset 392 (0x188) next 0 (0)
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<8>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<8>
BitsPerSample (258) SHORT (3) 3<16 16 16>
Compression (259) SHORT (3) 1<1>
Photometric (262) SHORT (3) 1<2>
StripOffsets (273) LONG (4) 1<8>
Orientation (274) SHORT (3) 1<1>
SamplesPerPixel (277) SHORT (3) 1<3>
RowsPerStrip (278) SHORT (3) 1<48>
StripByteCounts (279) LONG (4) 1<384>
PlanarConfig (284) SHORT (3) 1<1>
SampleFormat (339) SHORT (3) 3<1 1 1>
```

Comment: Prefer `"rb"` and `"wb"` with `TIFFOpen()` I think.

Comment: Try `tiffdump image.tif` to see the differences between your input and output files.

Comment: Tried "rb" and "wb" nothing changed :/ and tiffdump shows both images properties the same.

Comment: What about `tiffdump`?

Comment: Ugh! Don’t paste code and output in comments where you can’t format them. Rather, click `edit` under your question and paste it in there. The idea was to run `tiffdump` on your input and your output file in order to see the differences and work out what is wrong.

Comment: Opps sorry, I am new to stackoverflow.. :/ just joined it today.. let me copy paste the output in the question...

Comment: It's ok, we are all learning! So, the dumps look pretty much identical. Are the files much the same size as each other? What makes you believe the output is wrong?

Comment: Both images are different when displayed. When I give it a completely black picture as input the output image contains  colors.

Comment: Can you post a complete program so I, and other folks, can run tests within having to guess the missing parts? What platform are you using and what command do you compile with?

Comment: The above code is the whole program. I am using eclipse IDE and I build and run the program using the IDE, not any commands.

Answer (score 1):

When setting a value for TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL which is greater than 3 (sampleperpixel = 4 in your case), you may also need to set the TIFFTAG_EXTRASAMPLES field to an appropriate value.

See here:
https://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/samplesperpixel.html